# Array multiplication and matrix inversion with VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to do some calculations with arrays.

e.g. I want to solve `Ax=y`, so I use the following code to do so, where A is a square matrix and y is a col. vector. In VBA, A is an array with two dimension and y is one with one dimension. However, this code does not work...

```
x = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A), y)
```

Where did I get wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth It returns nothing and stop running...

Comment: Nothing? No error message? Please show us code that can do that... Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode?

Comment: You may find [Don’t invert that matrix](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) interesting. Be sure to read the comments too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can be committing one or more of many mistakes:

- Arrays not defined as `Variant` (Most worksheetfunctions won't work if data type is something other than `Variant`).
- Dimensions of `A` and `y` don't match up as they need to for matrix multiplication.
- In particular, won't work if `y` size is `(1,2)` instead of `(2,1)` as in example below.
- etc... Can be anything, really. You don't tell us what error message you get.

Here's an example that works:

```
Dim A As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim x As Variant

ReDim y(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
y(1, 1) = 2
y(2, 1) = 3

ReDim A(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
A(1, 1) = 3
A(2, 1) = 1
A(1, 2) = 4
A(2, 2) = 2

x = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A), y)
```

Comment: This is helpful. I think I committed all of the mistakes you mentioned above. BTW, the function returns no msg at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let matrix **A** (3 x 3) be an array in `Range("A1:C3")`, matrix **y** (3 x 1) be an array in `Range("E1:E3")`, and matrix **x** (3 x 1) be an array in `Range("G1:G3")`. Then you can try this simple program:

```
Range("G1:G3") = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.MInverse(Range("A1:C3")), Range("E1:E3"))
```

By using the same procedure, you can do this to find the result of multiplication of a matrix (n x m) with a matrix (p x q). Of course for the simplification you should declare the variables first. I hope this answer can help you.