# Why does a 2X1 array need to be defined as (1 to 2, 1 to 1) instead of just (1 to 2)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I am performing matrix multiplication of an inverted 2X2 matrix with a 2X1 matrix.  I kept getting errors and did some searching and stumbled upon this [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302784/array-multiplication-and-matrix-inversion-with-vba).  The answer is the bit of code below.

Why does y need to be defined as (1 to 2, 1 to 1) instead of just (1 to 2)?

```
Dim A As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim x As Variant

ReDim y(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
y(1, 1) = 2
y(2, 1) = 3

ReDim A(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
A(1, 1) = 3
A(2, 1) = 1
A(1, 2) = 4
A(2, 2) = 2

x = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A), y)
```

Comment: Your first sentence answers the question. You are multiplying matrices, so 2D arrays. Of course `Mmult` could have been implemented to handle 1D arrays as a 2D array with second dimension = 1, but it would require different handling of each case (1D x 1D, 1D x 2D, 2D x 1D). Microsoft apparently decided not to do that and requires both arrays to be 2D.

Comment: @BrakNicku its confusing to me because when I use the functions inside excel, I am supplying it with a 2X2 range and a 1X2 range. IE. `=MMULT(D5:E6,G5:G6)`

Comment: The second (G5:G6) is 2X1, but other than that I am not quite sure what exactly is confusing there. If you define a `v` Variant variable and assign `v=Range("G5:G6").Value` it is 2D array (exactly as your `A` array).

Comment: Its not intuitive to me that G5:G6 is a 2D array.  On the surface it looks very 1D to me

Comment: Does that mean if I have a 3X3 matrix and I want to multiply it with a 3X1 matrix that the second matrix would need to be (1 to 3, 1 to 1, 1 to 1) or (1 to 3, 1 to 1), I am thinking the later.

Comment: `(1 to 3, 1 to 1)`, the first dimension is always number of rows, the second number of columns (even if it is 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MMULT should have 2D arrays as parameters, since it is used for multiplying 2D matrices. A 1D array cannot be considered as a matrix.